# Nunit+Specflow , retry failed test

Tags: selenium-webdriver, nunit, specflow

I am using Nunit+Specflow+selenium to run UI tests.
My tests fail intermittently due to stale element reference .
Is there a way ,I can re-run those failed tests.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SpecRunner+ to do so. 
In Execution configuration it is possible to define:

- how many retries should be applied
- when retry should happen (on error, always)

More details you can find here:
https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow-runner/en/latest/Profile/Execution.html

Best regards,
PM